# How to calculate number of days between users first and last session in POSTGRESQL(no datediff)

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I am attempting to solve the following question"Given a table of user sessions write a query to get the number of days between each users first and last session for the year 2020"(can see the question in the full question details in the attached image).

Using POSTGRESQL but had little luck without Datediff. Can you kindly tell me how to solve it via POSTGRESQL? [Question details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjwvx.jpg)

In MySQL I used the following query to solve it :

```
select user_id,
datediff(max(date(created_at)),min(date(created_at))) as noofdays
from user_sessions
where Year(created_at)=2020
group by 1
order by 1;
```

to solve it

I cant replicate the logic in POSTGRE and my best attempt was

```
select user_id,
Extract(day from age(max(created_at),min(created_at))) as noofdays
from user_sessions
Where Extract(YEAR FROM created_at)=2020
group by user_id
order by user_id
```

but the results are different.

but results were different:

**user_id no of days**

```
3             18

4             2

5             15

7             15

9             26
```

compared to the expected output

**noofdays**

**user_id no of days**

```
3               323

4               247

5               320

7               228

9               240
```

Please can you tell me how to fix this and what I am doing wrong, I tried for a whole day but Im stuck. I also tried Date_part('day',max(created_at)-min(created_at))but sadly failed.

Comment: Select date2 -date1.

Comment: (A) By what time zone do you want to determine the year? (B) Did you mean calendar days? If so, by what time zone should we determine the date? Or did you mean generic 24-chunks of time? (C) Did you correctly define your `created_at` column as a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`? Or did you mistakenly use `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`?